# Android AVD crashes when app is run because of 'Mixing version can cause lead to runtime crashes'

Tags: android

Error is:

> All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version
>   specification (mixing versions can lead to runtime crashes). Found
>   versions 28.0.0, 26.1.0.

These are dependencies and appcompact view has red line under it

```
 dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
}
```

Main Activity.Java code is

```
package com.example.agecalculatorpro;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.DatePicker;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

Button btn1;
EditText age;
TextView result;
private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        MobileAds.initialize(this,
                "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        btn1.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
    String Input_year = age.getText().toString();
    result.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    if(Integer.parseInt(Input_year) < 2017)
    {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int current_year = calendar.get(calendar.YEAR);
        int current_age = current_year - Integer.parseInt(Input_year);
        result.setText("Your Age is: " + current_age);
    }
    else
    {
        result.setText("Please Enter Correct Year");
    }
    }
}
```

The app either keeps on crashing or does not compile at all. Different behaviour on different AVD.

This issue started after entering the admob line:
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
17 version also shows same error.
Before admob app used to run fine.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this can be easily fixed:

```
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.3") {
    exclude group: "com.android.support"
}
```

Comment: @johnsmith it's working, while otherwise providing the libraries which would conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind...I just selected wipe data on the AVD and now they run properly.
The red line for appcompat is as it is but the app still runs.